# Shell script date

Tags: shell, date

```
endDate=`date +%m-%d-%Y`
endDate=`expr $endDate -7`
echo "$endDate"
```

The above code gives error, but the one below runs properly. I want to use the date format above; how would I accomplish this?

```
TODAY=`date +%d`
TODAY=`expr $TODAY - 7`
echo $TODAY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting, "expr: non-integer argument", should show what kind of problem you're getting; when you try to subtract 7 from "04-14-2017", you don't get what you'd expect. To get last week, you can pass in the `-d` flag to get a specific date instead of the default of "now"

```
endDate=`date -d '7 days ago' +"%m-%d-%Y"`
echo $endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second set of commands works because `date +%d` returns a number, and you can subtract 7 from a number.  Your first set of commands fails because `date  +%m-%d-%Y` returns a string of characters, and you can't subtract 7 from a string.

Properly and safely doing date math is a little too complex for the `date` command, especially if you have a time zone with Daylight Saving time.  I recommend a perl module such as Date::EzDate or DateTime.

Comment: The proper way to manage this is convert initial date to seconds from 1970 (UTC), do the math using the second as unit, and then convert the final UTC to the desired date format